# Android: Sending email does not work in production:

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I used the logic in this link to send email for a feedback feature in my yet-to-be-released(to production) app.

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)

I tried sending an email with contents from a form upon the click of a submit button. It works fine with the build from Eclipse. The email gets sent to recipient email address

I then uploaded a Alpha version to the Google Play store. But when I Download the app and try it, recipient email address does not receive any emails.

I have the following permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

in my Android manifest.

I am using the same settings as mentioned in the above link. I am using an email address and password with correct credentials and a different recipient email address.

Could there be any possible firewall issues?

Thanks.

Comment: Post your codes as it's hard to figure out the problem without seeing the code. FYI: JavaMail works just fine if you don't want to use the Android mailing facility.

Comment: I am using the exact code as mentioned in that link. Just changing the credentials. I want to send the customer's feedback to my email with the click of a button. So in the OnClickListener of the button, I Am calling the GmailSender sender = new GmailSender("username@gmail.com", "password"); sender.sendMail(params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3]); Additionally I am using an async task to do this in the button's onclick listener

Comment: Do you have any firewall apps installed, like DroidWall, Android Firewall, etc? If you do, open the firewall app and enable WiFi or Mobile Network access for your app. Also, check that you have entered the password correctly in your WiFi setting if you use WiFi to send emails.

Comment: No I don't have any firewalls installed. I checked my WI-FI password and it is correctly set.

Comment: Can't say for sure why it doesn't work for you. Perhaps there's some special requirement/steps for setting up a package in Alpha or Beta stage that you have missed. Retrace your procedure for uploading the test package and see if you haved missed a step.